# How to INSERT list containing strings into variable and add them to IN clause later in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a question. How could I add list of strings to variable if I want to use them in IN clause.

Example:

I have got query containing IN clause like:

```
WHERE products_name IN ("Product1", "Product2", "Product3")
```

I would like to add this to variable like:

```
SET @products = ("Product1", "Product2", "Product3")
```

so I coulde use it like:

```
WHERE products_name IN (@products)
```

It returns error or empty results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support what you want to do.  You need to use a temporary table, or store the values in a string, or store the values as JSON, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SET @products = 'Product1,Product2,Product3';
```

and

```sql
... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(products_name, @products) ...
```

Pay attention - there is no spaces after commas in CSV value.

PS. This technique does not allow to use indices.